# Idenitifying pins in my code. which pin is which?

Tags: esp8266

I'm new to arduino and knnow nothing about electronics.
How do I idenitify which pin is which in the coding?
eg- I have a pin on my esp8266 "D3"... how would I reference that in the code?

Comment: You could try google search ...

Comment: You could either call it as just D3 in your code, or you could use the GPIO number which in this case is 0, do not get used to calling it Dx most boards are not capable of doing this

Answer (score 1):

If you select the right board in Tools menu, you can use constants corresponding to labels.

```
pinMode(D3, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(D3, LOW);
```

Comment: and of course, you can google "nodemcu pinout" and you will find nice pictures with all pins specs